# Installing patator on a mac

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install patator on my mac machine, needing it for a projectdoing some cracking.

So, I first attempted installing though pip:

```
pip3 install patator
```

This fails with:

```
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/91/bdfe808fb5dc99a5f65833b370818161b77ef6d1e19b488e4c146ab615aa/mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=06eb5664e3738b283ea2262ee60ed83192e898f019cc7ff251f4d05a564ab3b7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Collecting patator
  Using cached patator-0.8-py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
  Using cached patator-0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
Collecting psycopg2
  Downloading psycopg2-2.9.1.tar.gz (379 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 379 kB 3.3 MB/s 
ERROR: Cannot install patator==0.7, patator==0.8 and patator==0.9 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    patator 0.9 depends on mysqlclient
    patator 0.8 depends on mysqlclient
    patator 0.7 depends on mysqlclient

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies'
```

It's giving me two tips that I should not specify the package versions, but this is confusing to me, since I am not specifying any versions at all?

I also tried visiting the link that it gives me, but there's really no help at all there.

What's happening here? Why am I not able to install patator?

Comment: I tried running `pip install patator` in my mac machine and didn't find any problems. Have you updated `pip`? Try `pip install --upgrade pip` before installing `patator`.

Comment: running that renders me  `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable. Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (21.2.4)`